# awk error: each rule must have a pattern or an action part

Tags: linux, gawk

From [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/450627) I got the following command:

```
awk '/em1/ {i++; rx[i]=$2; tx[i]=$10}; END{print rx[2]-rx[1] " " tx[2]-tx[1]}' \
<(cat /proc/net/dev; sleep 1; cat /proc/net/dev)
```

which is fully working as intended. However, I would the output in Mbps, so I created 2 commands, one for upload, one for download (both working):

```
awk '/^e/ {i++; rx[i]=$2}; END{printf("%.2f Mbps", \
((rx[2]-rx[1])/1024/1024))}'  <(cat /proc/net/dev; sleep 1; \
cat /proc/net/dev)  # download

awk '/^e/ {i++; tx[i]=$10}; END{printf("%.2f Mbps", \
((tx[2]-tx[1])/1024/1024))}'  <(cat /proc/net/dev; sleep 1; \
cat /proc/net/dev)  # upload
```

But when I tried to combine then, but some errors came up:

```
$ awk '/^e/ {i++; rx[i]=$2}; tx[i]=$10}; \
END{printf(" down: %.2f Mbps, up: %.2f Mbps", \
((rx[2]-rx[1])/1024/1024)), ((tx[2]-tx[1])/1024/1024))}' \
<(cat /proc/net/dev; sleep 1; cat /proc/net/dev)

awk: cmd. line:1: /^e/ {i++; rx[i]=$2}; tx[i]=$10}; END{printf(" down: %.2f Mbps, up: %.2f Mbps", ((rx[2]-rx[1])/1024/1024)), ((tx[2]-tx[1])/1024/1024))}
awk: cmd. line:1:                                ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: each rule must have a pattern or an action part
awk: cmd. line:1: /^e/ {i++; rx[i]=$2}; tx[i]=$10}; END{printf(" down: %.2f Mbps, up: %.2f Mbps", ((rx[2]-rx[1])/1024/1024)), ((tx[2]-tx[1])/1024/1024))}
awk: cmd. line:1:                                                                                                           ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: /^e/ {i++; rx[i]=$2}; tx[i]=$10}; END{printf(" down: %.2f Mbps, up: %.2f Mbps", ((rx[2]-rx[1])/1024/1024)), ((tx[2]-tx[1])/1024/1024))}
awk: cmd. line:1:                                                                                                                                      ^ syntax error
```

I tried to solve it using `sprintf`, but the result was the same.

OS: Linux 4.0.5-1-ARCH x86_64 GNU/Linux

`awk`: GNU Awk 4.1.3, API: 1.1 (GNU MPFR 3.1.2-p11, GNU MP 6.0.0)

Comment: Look at the parentheses on the `printf` call closely. Also the braces on the first action block.

Comment: Instead of trying to combine the split commands try just adding the math to the first command.

Comment: Thank you, @EtanReisner, now it works (`awk '/^e/ {i++; rx[i]=$2; tx[i]=$10}; END{printf("down: %.2f Mbps, up: %.2f Mbps", ((rx[2]-rx[1])/1024/1024), ((tx[2]-tx[1])/1024/1024)) }' <(cat /proc/net/dev; sleep 1; cat /proc/net/dev)`). But I do not really understand your second comment―how should I add the math the the first command? I thought the above-mentioned command is the ‘math-added’ command. … Btw, if you make an answer from your first comment, I would mark it as a solution.

Comment: My point was that your problem came from splitting and then trying to re-combine. If you'd just added the math to the first version you likely wouldn't have introduced the problem you had in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The errors, as awk helpfully (though verbosely) tells you

```
awk: cmd. line:1: /^e/ {i++; rx[i]=$2}; tx[i]=$10}; END{printf(" down: %.2f Mbps, up: %.2f Mbps", ((rx[2]-rx[1])/1024/1024)), ((tx[2]-tx[1])/1024/1024))}
awk: cmd. line:1:                                ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: each rule must have a pattern or an action part
awk: cmd. line:1: /^e/ {i++; rx[i]=$2}; tx[i]=$10}; END{printf(" down: %.2f Mbps, up: %.2f Mbps", ((rx[2]-rx[1])/1024/1024)), ((tx[2]-tx[1])/1024/1024))}
awk: cmd. line:1:                                                                                                           ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: /^e/ {i++; rx[i]=$2}; tx[i]=$10}; END{printf(" down: %.2f Mbps, up: %.2f Mbps", ((rx[2]-rx[1])/1024/1024)), ((tx[2]-tx[1])/1024/1024))}
awk: cmd. line:1:                                                                                                                                      ^ syntax error
```

are that closing `}` because you already closed that action block at `rx[i]=$2};` before that and the `,` and the final `)` because the `printf` call was already closed. The complete function call is this:

```
printf(" down: %.2f Mbps, up: %.2f Mbps", ((rx[2]-rx[1])/1024/1024))
```

So the `,` and everything that follows it is a syntax error because it isn't a valid statement on its own.